# Change the value of a column with vba code rather than loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add `"#"` before each cell in a column (have more than 13000 cells), and add `"000"` to another column through vba excel code. I can achieve this with loop but it takes a long time when running the macro. Can anyone help me with more effective solutions?

```
for each cell in column
  cell = "#"& cell
  next cell

for each cell in column
   select case len(cell)
     case 2: cell = "'000" & cell
     case 3: cell = "'00" & cell
   end select
    
next cell
```

Desired result:

> 456 => #456
>
> 10 => 00010

however it runs very slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use display format:

```
Range("A1:A1300").NumberFormat = "\##"
Range("B1:B1300").NumberFormat = "00000"
```

This does not change the underlying value, but it will display correctly.

To read the value out use Cell.Text to retrieve a string with the leading zeros.

Comment: Hi Storm. i've tested but Cell.Text only seems only work when i print out through msgbox. i can't assign or change the the real value. eg: range("c1")= range("a1").text